# How to make address fields not required in checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

In the onepage checkout the next fields are required by default:

- Address
- City
- Zipcode
- country

I don't want that this fields are required. Add the moment we only send virtual products so we don't need the fields.

I have tried to remove the required class in the billing.html but that does not work. I get a popup message that het address field is required and has to have a minimal length of 1.